# MailBee Imap.Connect throws an Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow error

Tags: c#, email, imap

I have an old program that I have been asked to update. It was originally built using .NET framework 2. I have updated this to version 4.5.

The code uses MailBee to connect to an email account and the old version works. The updated version however throws an "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" error when I call the Connect function of the Imap object.

```
MailBee.Global.SafeMode = true;
Imap imap = new Imap();
imap.Log.Enabled = true;
imap.Log.Filename = control.MailBeeLogDir + "MailBee_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".log";
imap.SslMode = MailBee.Security.SslStartupMode.OnConnect;
imap.Connect(control.EmailServer, control.EmailPort);
```

The log file has no errors and seems to connect successfully.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the email server name to let me check?

Comment: Outlook.office365.com 993
I am using version 3.0.2.77 of MailBee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a very old version of MailBee.NET Objects (v3). The up-to-date version is v12. Update to the latest version and try again.

Comment: If I update I then get an out of date licence error

Comment: If you don't want to update, it won't be possible to help you.